# DataGridView + SqlData Source Madness

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, sqldatasource

I am trying to populate data from a table created in `aspnetdb.mdf` that has game data stored in it, which has a `uniqueidentifier` that is `UserId` that is the users Asp Membership `UserId`. I want to select the users data from the table using a `SqlDataSource` and populate it into the `DataGridView`.

I have read thread after thread, and MSDN documentation, and for the life of me I can't get this joker to work. The `DataGridView` isn't even displayed, just a blank screen. In the designer I can see the columns I wan't to select.. Here is the code. If anyone has an idea, answer, or **anything** I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried switching the parameter data types and just about anything I can think of, but that didn't work

In code behind:

```
protected void userGameData_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser User = Membership.GetUser();
    object UserGUID = User.ProviderUserKey;

    userGameData.SelectParameters["UserId"].DefaultValue = UserGUID.ToString();

}
```

in aspx

```
<form id="frm" runat="server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="userGameData" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [cycleday], [playerwins], [housewins], [gametype], [gamedate], [phase] FROM [GameData] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)" OnSelecting="userGameData_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="rawGameResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="userGameData">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cycleday" HeaderText="cycleday" SortExpression="cycleday" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="playerwins" HeaderText="playerwins" SortExpression="playerwins" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="housewins" HeaderText="housewins" SortExpression="housewins" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="gametype" HeaderText="gametype" SortExpression="gametype" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="gamedate" HeaderText="gamedate" SortExpression="gamedate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="phase" HeaderText="phase" SortExpression="phase" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks fine. If you remove the `WHERE` clause is anything displayed?

Comment: No, Nothing is displayed :\

Comment: If I delete the WHERE clause alone, nothing changes. However, If I delete that and the OnSelecting event and the <SelectParameters /> I get all the data.. must be something to do with the UserID, which I've been trying to figure out the whole time. I can do this easily using a dataset and a few lines of code, but I want to use the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the bind is not working from the markup, I would try it from code-behind

```
   string sql = "SELECT [cycleday], [playerwins], [housewins], [gametype], [gamedate], [phase] FROM [GameData] WHERE UserId = (SELECT [UserId] FROM aspnet_users WHERE UserName = '" & User.Identity.Name & "')";
   using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
     using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection))
     {
       myConnection.Open();
       using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
       {
         DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
         myTable.Load(myReader);
         myConnection.Close();

         YourDataGridView.DataSource = myTable;
         YourDataGridView.DataBind();
       }
     }
   }
```

Set `connectionString` to the CS you are using in your project :)

Comment: I have tried this, and while it does work I would like to take advantage of automatic sorting and paging that the GridView provides when you use a SqlDataSource

Comment: However, after all these issues, maybe I shouldn't be so lazy and handle the event myself as I can see it isn't too difficult. Thank you (: